# color not changing in font icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to change font icon color but its not changing and i tried to increase font icon size by changing `font-size: 50px;` but it does't work

HTML

```
<section id="glyphs"><div class="glyph">
            <div class="glyph-icon airplane70"></div>
            <div class="class-name">.flaticon-airplane70</div></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Flaticon";
src: url("flaticon.eot");
src: url("flaticon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
url("flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
url("flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
url("flaticon.svg") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {   
font-family: Flaticon;
    font-size: 50px;
font-style: normal;
margin-left: 20px;
}.airplane70:before {
content: "\e000";
    color: #009900;
}
.flaticon-baby110:before {
content: "\e001";
    color: blue;
 }
```

I downloaded font icon from this site http://www.flaticon.com Can some one help whats wrong? I just need to change color of icon.

Comment: The files you are pulling down off of flaticon aren't subject to CSS rules. Depending on the format of the file you downloaded (SVG, PNG, etc) they need to be changed at the source level of the file.  So open them with an image editor and change there.

Comment: `.airplane70 {color: #009900;}`?

Comment: Are you overwriting an existing CSS ? Try adding "!important" after the color value. I.E. : color: blue !important;

Comment: no i download font icon format but i does't work

Comment: The code posted does not even cause a flaticon font to be used, since `flaticon-...` classes are not used. Post the code that you actually use. There is probably some CSS code involved that overrides your attempts at setting color or font size.

Comment: Are you not trying to use glyphicon here? `No markup for flaticon`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding color like this
CSS:

color:black;

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Flaticon";
  src: url("./Flaticon.eot");
  src: url("./Flaticon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("./Flaticon.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("./Flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
       url("./Flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("./Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("./Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  }
}

[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {   
  font-family: "Flaticon";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  color:black;
  line-height: 1;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  text-transform: none;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.flaticon-reload:before { content: "\f100"; }
.flaticon-download:before { content: "\f101"; }
.flaticon-monitor:before { content: "\f102"; }
.flaticon-chat:before { content: "\f103"; }
.flaticon-glasses:before { content: "\f104"; }
.flaticon-vector:before { content: "\f105"; }
```